# ng-repeat angularjs es6 not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-ng-repeat

please. help. I have officially looked at so many tutorials my brain is about to completely implode. Save me, stackoverflow, you are my only hope.

I am trying to use ng-repeat to get a list of cars to display. I have tried this many different ways to no avail.

Home view:

```
<h2>
  Welcome to homepage</h2>
<p>{{controller.message}}</p>
<li ng-repeat="car in controller.cars">
{{car.name}}
</li>
</body>
```

controllers.ts

```
namespace myapp.Controllers {

    export class HomeController {
        public message = 'Hello from the home page!';
        public movies;

        constructor(carService:myapp.Services.CarService) {
            this.cars = carService.listCars();
        }
    }


    export class AboutController {
        public message = 'Hello from the about page!';
    }

}
```

services.ts

```
namespace myapp.Services {

    export class CarService {
        private CarResource;

        public listCars() {
            return this.CarResource.query();
        }

        constructor($resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
            this.CarResource = $resource('/api/cars');
        }
    }
    angular.module('myapp').service('carService', CarService);
    export class MyService {

    }
    angular.module('myapp').service('myService', MyService);
    }
```

so basically.... I need to get the car API to give me information --- it does not seem like it is doing this. I have tried to use $http instead of resource. nope. I have read and reread the code. I need a nudge in the right direction. I've looked over the code so many times playing the connect-the-dots game and I just am not seeing what is missing here. It doesn't seem like it is getting any data from the API (I have put console.log in a couple places to check this, and nothing) so there is something going on with not being able to connect the API to the rest of my code. I just am not entirely sure what exactly.

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you see the *"Hello from the home page!"* message? I don't know TypeScript very well but does not having `public cars` in your controller affect the property visibility in the template?

Comment: yes I do see that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be silly question, Is there any issue with controller name while accessing it from your template?

Ignore this if not.